# Rainwater Pooling Under Backyard Gate

Tags: drainage

I'm trying to figure out how to fix rainwater pooling under my gate. The core issue here is that there is a small slope from my back porch steps/walkway to the back gate and a slope going the other direction on the other side of the gate so all rainwater pools under the gate. I have consulted a friend who thinks a French Drain will not work because of the sloping of the landscape in opposite directions under the gate. Any suggestions?

Comment: have a picture for us ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick replies. I will post a photo tomorrow when the sun is up.

Comment: You would need a lower elevation spot for the French drain to dump its water. The pipe should slope 1/8" down per foot, so distance to this lower elevation spot will determine whether or not a French drain is feasible.

Comment: A french drain will work fine as long as you have the elevation drop to somewhere you can daylight it.

Comment: You might search the internet for the term "rain garden." It would take a bunch of digging, but without cooperative ground elevations, it's that or redoing the concrete (or using a pump).

Answer (score -1):

The way I break down this kind of problem is that I need to make at least one of three things happen:

1. raise the surface so it’s not the low point (eg, throw some gravel in the hole).
2. drain the water to a lower point (dig a ditch whose bottom slopes downhill as it heads to a lower spot; it may even percolate down through the soil enough to solve the problem. fill with gravel, top with turf optional).  Perf pipe would add some open space that would act as a holding tank to give a heavy rain more time to sink in.
3. Curtail the runoff that’s contributing (causing?) the problem.  Are there overflowing gutters or open downspouts?

Comment: Thank for you for your quick response. I will post a photo tomorrow. While gravel may be a solution.  I would have to pile over a sidewalk that goes under the gate and out to the alley way.

Comment: Thanks for the pics. Better practice here, however, would be to insert the pictures directly into your question, so the viewer does not have to navigate to another location and the pictures will remain visible with the question. To do that, click on the "Edit" button below your question, then press the "Moon and Mountains" button on the text edit page that follows.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the edit of my own post was deleted by another admin for asking a new question. Well, I thought I was editing my original post with additional information.